# python readline wrongly judges the file end

Tags: python, readline

I have a text file to be read into mysql using python's readline() to read line by line.

The issue I am having is the text file has 100+ lines but 75th line is a blank line, 0d0a, readline() thinks the file reaches its end and so stops there.

How do I prevent that?

Thank you very much.

P.S. Below is my code and portion from the sample file:

```
for line in ipv4file:
if line:
    lineSplit = line.split( )

    ip_start = lineSplit[0]

    # define a tuple data to hold the parameters, remove all the leading and trailing blank spaces
    data = (lineSplit[0].lstrip().rstrip(), lineSplit[1].lstrip().rstrip(), lineSplit[2].lstrip().rstrip())

    sqltemplate = """
        insert into ipv4(ip_start, ip_end, ip_owner) values (%s, %s, %s)
    """
```

[image]

The file in HEX format:
[image]

Please note there are 0D 0A 0D 0A just before 1.6.0.0

Thanks.

Comment: There is no such thing as a blank line in the middle of a file. Every line other than the last one has a linefeed at the end.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this problem

Comment: `readline` should read that line as `"\n"` (or `"\r\n"` depending on how you opened it) and continue reading the following lines. Can you post an example where this fails? Maybe take that 100+ line file, trim most of it and post what remains. You could even do `print(base64.encodestring(open('f.py', 'rb').read()).decode('ascii'))
` so that we can decode that base64 string and get your exact file back.

Comment: And can you post a small example script that fails on your data? It could be a bug such as you doing `line = line.strip();if not line: break` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for posting the details. Your code will raise an index exception on the line you reference. If line: doesn't filter out blank lines as you expect because the line still has a newline in it. Read line isn't stopping,  your code is crashing.

Comment: Thank you @tdelaney, can you help on the fix?

Comment: I changed the problematic `if line:` to `    if line[0:2] != '\n':`, and it is working now. Thanks.

Comment: Put `line = line.strip()` before the if... that will work as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have a check for an empty line:

```
if line:
```

But it won't work because the newline character is still part of `line`. You can modify your test slightly to make it work:

```
if line.strip():
```

Answer (score 0):

The readline() actually read the line into a string tuple, which means 0D 0A will be read into a tuple of ("\n"), so all I need to do is to check the string, if the first two characters are "\n", then it means this line is an empty line, all I need to do is to skip it.

Thanks.